# Building the mmh3 package from source

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, pip, mingw32

I am essentially inexperienced with building python libraries from source, but it seems as though 'mmh3' is not available in binary form. I'm attempting to build a simple Bloom filter and mmh3 is needed for its hashing functionality. If someone could explain the process of building from source using MinGW on a WinXP machine, I would appreciate it. The source file is in the .tar.gz format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and easiest thing to try is installing it with pip, the Python package manager. If you're not familiar with pip, documentation is [at pip-installer.org](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/quickstart.html). If you want help getting it installed on Windows, see [this useful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Once you have pip, the command you run will be simply `pip install mmh3`

Also, if you don't need murmur hash specifically, definitely check out [Python's included hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html).